# EFCore 3.1 FromSqlRaw is not working and throwing a bizarre error message

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the most bizarre issue with EF Core 3.1. In EF Core 2.2 I used to be able to execute stored procedures. I see there is a breaking change in the documentation but, I am following the documentation exactly and it is not working. I have no nulls anywhere in the returned data. The NoticeOfInspection object matches the returned data exactly. What on Earth did they change that this is not working?

```
var data = _dbContext.NoticeOfInspections.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.NewReportApp_NoticeOfInspection {0}", FacilityId).Single();
```

The error message is not helpful at all. First with the above line, it says, "InvalidOperationException: FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling `AsEnumerable` after the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client side."

What?

So, I add AsEnumerable and then it throws, "InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'."

What on Earth have they done. This is not intuitive at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL

The non-composable SQL is the one which cannot be converted to subquery `select * from (your_sql)`. Calling SP (`EXEC …`) is one of the non-composable constructs.

> and with a query composing over it

Non query returning LINQ operators like `Single`, `First`, `Count`, `Max`, `Sum` etc. require composing over the provided SQL query, for instance `select count * from (your_query)`.

You can read more about it in [Raw SQL queries - Composing with LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#composing-with-linq) documentation topic, which also contains the "calling SP" and other limitations/restrictions:

> Composing with LINQ requires your raw SQL query to be composable since EF Core will treat the supplied SQL as a subquery. SQL queries that can be composed on begin with the `SELECT` keyword. Further, SQL passed shouldn't contain any characters or options that aren't valid on a subquery, such as:
>
> - A trailing semicolon
> - On SQL Server, a trailing query-level hint (for example, `OPTION (HASH JOIN))`
> - On SQL Server, an `ORDER BY` clause that isn't used with `OFFSET 0` OR `TOP 100 PERCENT` in the `SELECT` clause
>
> SQL Server doesn't allow composing over stored procedure calls, so any attempt to apply additional query operators to such a call will result in invalid SQL. Use `AsEnumerable` or `AsAsyncEnumerable` method right after `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated` methods to make sure that EF Core doesn't try to compose over a stored procedure.

With that being said, inserting `AsEnumerable()` before `Single()` should really work.

The new exception you are getting is either EF Core bug or data type mapping issue (either you are passing `int` to `string` parameter, or SP is returning `int` for `string` class property). You need to examine the exception stack trace and/or compare your SP parameter and column types to `FacilityId` argument type and `NoticeOfInspection` class property types/mappings.

Comment: For some bizarre reason, my key cannot be a string. I don't understand what could be wrong with using a string for a key, but, EF Core is definitely unhappy about it. It doesn't matter if I use the [Key] metadata or not. It doesn't even make any sense that I have to have a key for a stored procedure in the first place. EF is failing at the simplest possible task - mapping data from SQL into an object.

Comment: It definitely allows strings keys. Also it doesn't require keys at all in case the class is mapped as [keyless](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations). But you just seem to have data type discrepancy. And btw, mapping data from raw SQL to object is not the primary goal of EF - there are a lot of other libraries (like Dapper) which can do that. Anyway, I think all this falls outside the scope of the original question, which is *EFCore 3.1 FromSqlRaw is not working and throwing a bizarre error message* and I believe has been answered here.

Comment: Fair enough. You provided the answer although it is all the exact same documentation I have already read three times that did not resolve my issue. There is a bug if you do not have a field named Id and you use the [Key] data annotation on your key attribute. I should have included the mapped class.

Comment: @tnk479 I never exclude the possibility of hitting EF Core bug (they have a lot). But if the actual problem is the exception after inserting `AsEnumerable()`, then you should have concentrated on that - as you said, include the mapped class and fluent configuration etc. If you want, you can post another question with these details and I'll be happy to look at it.